# Character encoding issue in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

When I run a query directly in MySQL using phpMyAdmin it allows `–` (long dash, not normal `-`), but when I run this query from my PHP code, it turns them to `â€“`.

If you encode – it'll come `%E2%80%93` (in JavaScript). `%E2` becomes `â`, `%80` becomes `€` and `%93` becomes `“`. I don't understand when I run the query in phpMyAdmin it saves data as `–`, but when I run the query in my PHP code, then it does not work in the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which character encoding do you use in your table? After connecting to the DB in php try to run this:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); //if you use utf-8
```

Comment: Do you mean Collation of the filed? It's "latin1_swedish_ci".

BTW, your suggestion worked. Thank You very much!

Comment: @Debiprasad: Unless you are swdish, you should shwitch to utf-8. It makes life easier.

Comment: Even if you *are* swedish, a switch to UTF-8 won't hurt. :)

Comment: So you guys suggest to use this:
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
Thank you!

Comment: I modified my database, table and column to utf8, also removed mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); - now I can see now old issue.

Earlier those are in "latin1_swedish_ci" and I added mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); to my code. Here I was not experiecing the issue.

I need to learn more on this and will update about this here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe phpMyAdmin engine escapes long dash to normal dash ?

Comment: No, it does not escapes long dash to normal dash.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing to put the met tag on your HTML, have you write the next line in the head of your HTML document?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Otherwise, the browser interprets it as ISO-8859-1.

You should use the same encoding everywhere, on your database, on your connection and on your html document.

For ensure you have a utf-8 table, run the next statement, and check it says **CHARSET=utf8** almost at the end.

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName;
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem. Thank you.

Comment: The query returns: DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1